# Cannot reload Visual C++ projects compiled with platform toolset v141_xp

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

I have a Visual Studio 2015 C++ project that was compiling using the toolset v140_xp.

When I open the same project with Visual Studio 2017 I am able to change the toolset to v141_xp and compile the project without errors.

But if I save the project, close Visual Studio and reopen it the project fails to load and I receive the following error:

```
One or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctly. Please see the Output Window for details
```

Here the output window

```
Project '<Name>' could not be loaded because it's missing install components. To fix this launch Visual Studio setup with the following selections:
Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.NativeDesktop.WinXP

<Path>\<Name>-vs2017.vcxproj : error  : The application for the project is not installed.
```

What could be the cause and how can I solve it?

[image]

Comment: A pretty typical VS2017 problem, this [is brittle](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/30043/uninstalling-windows-xp-support-for-c-does-not-rem.html).  First run the installer and verify that the "Windows XP support for C++" option is turned on.  Next use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem.